Cannot resolve symbol "TimeUnit"
I have imported here TimeUnit manually. But still IDE(IntelliJ) is not recognising the import
package com.akashonlinehere.aopdemo.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Service
public class TrafficFortuneServiceImpl implements TrafficFortuneService {

    @Override
    public String getFortune() {

        // simulate a delay

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // return a fortune
        return "Expect heavy traffic this morning";
    }
}

I was expecting that with this code it should sleep for 5 seconds.
But it is giving me error

Which version of java (jdk, jre) do you use?

This sounds a bit like that problem. Make sure you are not using an outdated IntelliJ version with a new JDK it cannot handle yet. Upgrade the version, if neccesary multiple times.
